# Lorentz-invariance Lagrangian for a free particle and $\frac{d}{d \tau} \left( m \eta_{\mu \nu} u^{\mu}\right)=0$

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, euler-lagrange-equation, special-relativity

Considering a Lorentz-invariance Lagrangian for a free particle
$$L=\frac{m}{2}\eta_{\nu \mu}u^{\mu}u^{\nu}$$ 
In the coordinates you use the Minkowski metric has constant components so the Euler-Lagrange equation: 
$$\frac{d}{d \tau} \left( m \eta_{\mu \nu} u^{\mu}\right)=0$$

I do not understand why.
I think we need to replace $L=\frac{m}{2}\eta_{\nu \mu}u^{\mu}u^{\nu}$ in $$\dfrac{d}{dt} \left( \dfrac{ \partial L} { \partial \dot{q}^{ \lambda}} \right)- \dfrac{ \partial L}{ \partial q^{ \lambda}} = 0$$
But in the passages I got stuck.
The second equality I do not understand is:
$$\frac{d}{d \tau}(\eta_{\nu \mu} u^{\mu}u^{\nu})= 2 u^{\nu}\frac{d}{d \tau}(\eta_{\nu \mu} u^{\mu})=0$$

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352073/2451

Answer (score 0):

$\eta_{\mu\nu}u^\mu u^\nu$ is an invariant equal to $\pm c^2$ depending on the signature of your metric.  Thus its derivative w/r to $\tau$ (which is another invariant) is automatically $0$.